# Filter multiple dataframe columns on a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that contains 5 **Player** columns which contain random player names. I want to be able to pass in a list of players and only return rows where both players are present in that row (across those 5 columns).

This is the code that generates the dataframe and successfully filters out rows that contain either person in the row. How would I go about making sure that the row contains both people?

```
random_events = ('SHOT', 'MISSED_SHOT', 'GOAL')
random_team = ('Preferred', 'Other')
events = list()

for i in range(6):
    event = dict()
    event['event_type'] = random.choice(random_events)
    event['team'] = random.choice(random_team)
    event['coords_x'] = round(random.uniform(-100, 100), 2)
    event['coords_y'] = round(random.uniform(-42.5, 42.5), 2)
    event['person_1'] = f'Person {random.randint(1, 2)}'
    event['person_2'] = f'Person {random.randint(3, 4)}'
    event['person_3'] = f'Person {random.randint(5, 6)}'
    event['person_4'] = f'Person {random.randint(7, 8)}'
    event['person_5'] = f'Person {random.randint(9, 10)}'
    events.append(event)

df = pd.DataFrame(events)
print(df)


filter_list = ['Person 1', 'Person 3']
filtered_df = df.loc[
    (df['person_1'].isin(filter_list)) |
    (df['person_2'].isin(filter_list)) |
    (df['person_3'].isin(filter_list)) |
    (df['person_4'].isin(filter_list)) |
    (df['person_5'].isin(filter_list))]

print(filtered_df)
```

This is the result I get -- showing rows with only Person 1 or Person 3, as well as Person 1 and Person 3 are returned. In the example below I would only want Row with Index 2 returned to me

```
   coords_x  coords_y   event_type  person_1  person_2  person_3  person_4   person_5       team
0     38.82    -39.18  MISSED_SHOT  Person 1  Person 4  Person 6  Person 7   Person 9   Preferred
2     94.43     30.13         GOAL  Person 1  Person 3  Person 5  Person 8   Person 9       Other
3    -68.38    -24.42  MISSED_SHOT  Person 2  Person 3  Person 5  Person 7  Person 10   Preferred
4     99.48     22.79         SHOT  Person 1  Person 4  Person 5  Person 7   Person 9   Preferred
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a general approach. You'll probably want to play around with it depending on your exact situation.

```
# Define a list of all of the person columns in the dataframe
person_cols = [f'person_{i}' for i in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]

# Which rows contain Person 2 in any column? (creates a series of True or False)
(df[person_cols] == "Person 2").any(axis='columns')

# Which rows contain both Person 2 and Person 3? 
# This time I'm saving the series to use as a selection mask
mask = (
        (df[person_cols] == "Person 2").any(axis='columns') 
      & (df[person_cols] == "Person 3").any(axis='columns') 
)

# show just the rows where the mask above is True
print(df[mask])
```

### Edit:

Setting up a mask for an arbitrary list of players who must all be present.

```
from operator import and_
from functools import reduce

players = ['Player 1', 'Player 3', 'Player 4']
filters = [(df[person_cols] == p).any(axis='columns') for p in players]
mask = reduce(and_, filters, True)

print(df[mask])
```

Comment: This is a great approach and seems to work really well. Just a note, I had to change `axis='rows'` to `axis='columns'` for this to work correctly. But if I had a dynamic length of filters within the mask, how could I do that in some type of `for` loop?

Comment: Thanks! I'll edit the post. For a variable list of filters you'll need to `import operator` to get the function version of `&`. Something along the lines of `reduce(operator.and_, list_of_filters, True)` should work.

Comment: I actually found something on Stack Overlow where I make a list of masks and then run this code - `mask = np.logical_and.reduce(mask_list)`, which works really well, but if I don't have to import NumPy just for this (only use in the code) that would be awesome too!

Comment: I put the `operator.and_` solution in an edit. However, the numpy solution you found looks nicer still. There's really nothing wrong with depending on numpy, because you are already using pandas which itself depends on numpy.